# Python how to print strings containing numbers

Tags: python, string

I have a list :

```
var = ["renderPass1", "renderPass2","renderPass3", "renderPassFilter", "renderPassSets"]
```

How do I print only renderPass1, renederPass2 etc, I mean, print only members containing number after "renderPass"

Comment: Are you saying strings that contain numbers or strings that contain a number _after_ `"renderPass"`?  In other words, is the position of the number relevant?

Comment: Actually both of them. All answers are quite useful and different from each other. Regular expressions are pretty useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression to look for a digit.

Check out the python library: [Python: Re](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) .  Your going to want to look at "\d".

A tool that helps me a lot of with regex is [Txt to Regex](http://txt2re.com/).  You simply put in the string you want to match and build the regex with a GUI.  It then provides the code for you bellow.

Comment: +1 for mentionning regular expression. An example of this in python would be fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for value in var:
    if value[-1].isdigit(): # check if last char is a number
         print value
```

Now if you want to test the string for "renderPass"

```
  for value in var:
        if 'renderPass' in value and value[-1].isdigit()
             print value
```

Answer (score 2):

I will give two answers because your question wasn't too clear on what is considered a match.

This is for if the position of the number is *not* relevant:

```
>>> var = ["renderPass1", "renderPass2","renderPass3", "renderPassFilter", "renderPassSets"]
>>> [x for x in var if any(c.isdigit() for c in x)]
['renderPass1', 'renderPass2', 'renderPass3']
>>>
```

And this is for if the number has to come after `"renderPass"`:

```
>>> from re import search
>>> # I altered the values in here so I could demonstrate
>>> var = ["renderPass1", "renderPass2","renderPass3", "1renderPassFilter", "1renderPassSets"]
>>> [x for x in var if search("renderPass.*\d", x)]
['renderPass1', 'renderPass2', 'renderPass3']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you require only the pattern with "SomeTextNumber" you can write like this

```
[x for x in var if re.match("\w+\d$", x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

pick one depending on how much you know about whats in your list.

print first 3

```
print var[:3]
```

print any name with pattern `renderPass` followed by a digit

```
print [name for name in var if name.startswith('renderPass') and name[9].isdigit()]
```

print any name with a digit anywhere in it

```
print [name for name in var if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in name)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for name in var:
    try:
        float(name[len("renderPass"):])
        print name
    except ValueError, er:
        # does not have a number after renderPass -> do nothing
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
p = re.compile("[0-9]$")
for s in var:
    if p.search(s): print s
```